# IMAP, Microsoft Exchange, Searching Emails

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, imap

I am currently working on a web app, that is essentially a CRM. The client wants to be able to do all his day to day business tasks through the CRM.

The major point he wishes to have is the ability to send and receive emails from within his web app. Is this possible using IMAP? Could I get message threads etc?

The other major point is that if he views a client profile he would like to see the email threads for that client. Is that possible? Can I retrieve emails based on the recipient or sender email address?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve email with IMAP, but not send with it. IMAP also does have the ability to handle threading, and as far as being able to view the threads for clients, I suppose that can be done so long as the permissions are properly setup.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-thread.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php for more info.