# Catching emails with a script, then deleting

Tags: php, email, smtp, imap, lamp

I need to create a system that will pipe incoming emails to a PHP script, then get rid of the email. Technically, I don't want these email addresses to actually exist. I would want to validate the email address by checking a database. So if I have a database with say 100 email addresses (i.e. 2323@mydomain.com), the PHP script would parse the email, store the contents in a database for later use, and then discard the email.

I piped emails to a PHP script in the past and parsed the email. However, my understanding of this requires the email address to exist.

I figure a catch-all account would be a bad idea, as SPAM could account for the majority of incoming emails, which I have no use for.

I could create the emails dynamically perhaps, if that is even possible with PHP, but again, I don't actually need to store the incoming email. Eventually the server would get bogged down with emails that I have no use for, especially since the contents would be stored in a database.

There will be no manual management of the incoming emails. Everything would be automated. While I'm sure I could use the PHP imap extension to delete emails say every 30 days, this seems unnecessary.

Any suggestions on the best setup for this?

- Automation of email address creation or wildcard catch
- Parsing of email, storing and discarding

Comment: what is the type of email server? SMTP or exchange?

Comment: SMTP. I would love to do it with the default local mail, but if I had to beef it up that would be fine. I would expect a large sum of emails to a large amount of addresses.

Comment: 1) Which MTA/SMTP server do you use? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...] 2) Does `user+detail@mydomain.com` fit you needs? [static `user`, variable `detail` ]

Comment: Currently, I have nothing setup. I plain to use the local-mail setup with PHP, but I can use something else. The email ID can be anything@mydomain.com. Would a catch-all be a bad idea? I don't actually need to keep the emails. I could pipe the email, then discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at a GitHub Project [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and the documentation is available [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/).

You can also try [sendgrip](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), another good SMTP mailer for PHP.

These projects do not have a direct functions to delete e-mails, however, you will have to bake your own code extending some of the classes. Good Luck!

Comment: These look great for sending emails, and PHPMailer seems to allow for script based email address creation. Based on this, would you recommend piping the emails to a script, or reading them directly using the PHP imap extension?

Comment: i would recommend to do it through a script. This way you will have more control over the flow of the code and would be easier to manage

Comment: Have a look at [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089970/imap-microsoft-exchange-searching-emails

Answer (score 0):

See http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/ for an excellent article that explains how to pipe incoming mail to a PHP script.  You should be able to configure your MTA with a wildcard on your domain (so that it accepts mail to anyaddress@yourdomain.tld) and forward each incoming message to your PHP script.  Your PHP script can then pickup the sender, recipient, subject, etc., query your database, and process the message accordingly.